# nodejs forEach or map

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, dictionary, foreach

I have a loop problem. Loop start after 46 again. I can't understand where is problem?

The Codes are here:

```
Outsource = {key:1, value1:{
                     butce:{"fiyat":655000000, birim:"TL" }
                     projeAdi: MEBİS
.
.
.
}

Outsource.forEach((x, i)=>{
    let snc = (x.value1.butce.birim.includes("TL") ?
 parseFloat(x.value1.butce.fiyat) : 0)
    toplamButce = Number(toplamButce + snc)
    console.log(i +" // "+toplamButce.toString().length+" // "+toplamButce.toString() + " // "+ x.value1.projeAdi + " // " + snc)
})
```

Loop Outputs are:

```
39 // 11 // 24086357500 // MEBİS // 655000000
44 // 11 // 24923057500 // Wimax LTE // 836700000
45 // 11 // 24941957500 // Egitim // 18900000
46 // 11 // 24992396000 // Otomatik Araç // 50438500
0 // 10 // 2000000000 // Fiber // 2000000000
1 // 11 // 12000000000 // LTE Geniş Bant // 10000000000
2 // 11 // 12030000000 // GSM Geçiş // 30000000
3 // 11 // 12107000000 // Altyapı Geçiş // 77000000
4 // 11 // 14707000000 // Sayısal Telsiz // 2600000000
```

Please help. Thank im Advance.

Comment: Looks like `Outsource` is an object.

Comment: Thanks :) i wrote here false. But it is array otherwise it can't work .

Comment: Maybe you have a sparse array.

Comment: you are right. because of sparse array. Very very Thanks. :)